# in QT I Can't create project with a Kit

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I am using:

1. Ubuntu Mate 16.04
2. Qt Creator 3.5.1
3. Qt version 4.8.7
4. Installed on Intel Box

I am trying to make a ARM console application that will run on the SolidRun Hummingboard.

I have all of the ARM cross compile tools installed.  I added the compiler.
I made a generic linux device.  Made a Kit from these and the kit does not show any errors.

But when I start a new project it only gives me the choice of the "Desktop" kit. Nothing I try will allow me to select another kit.

I have checked and the "remote" plugin is installed.

Why am I only seeing "Supported Platforms: Desktop" and not my other kits?

Comment: Do you have Qt compiled  for the ARM board?

Comment: Can you cross-compile Qt apps from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I can compile from the command line.  I do have the compiled Qt libraries on the ARM board.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't have a valid cross-compiled Qt installed to begin with, so until you get that done, you'll go nowhere.** There are several reasons why it's so:

1. You can't move Qt from the target to the host, Qt consists of a target-specific and host-specific part. The host-specific part from the target won't work on your development machine.
2. You can't move Qt to a different folder. qmake hardcodes the install path so you'd have to put Qt into exactly the same folder.
3. You need a local build anyway to debug into Qt's code. This is really helpful, and you won't be very productive without a local debug and release builds, both of which should include debug information.

Thus, you first need to compile Qt using your cross-compiler. Then add that *Qt Version* to Qt Creator, making sure you've selected the right compiler. Then click "Apply". Only then you'll be able to create a kit using that Qt version. And then you'll be able to use the kit for development. You likely have a non-functional kit because you don't have a matching Qt install for it to use.

Remember that each target/compiler requires its own build of Qt, and that build is known as a "Qt Version" in Qt Creator parlance.

Comment: I can not even get the kit to load if I pick a Non-Qt application.  And I already have the QT libs installed on my target system.  Can I just move those over to my development system and then just point to them?

Comment: I was trying to use qtcreator as a general purpose IDE to compile a command line program that did not use the qt libraries at all.  I guess this is a bad tool for that and I probably should of used code::blocks or eclipse.  But I wanted to use qmake.